# My div does not exists after loading my pixel

Tags: javascript

I have a pixel and when I load it, it says:

```
a call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored
```

and then displays:

```
document.getElementById('gospixel') is null
```

Here's my pixel code:

```
<script name="gospix" src="http://www.example.com/p/gospixel.js">
```

and in that file:

```
gos_f=42;
gos_a1='a2';
gos_u=window.location.href;
gos_k='6gZYlfy7Y7Q';
gos_rt='3_s';
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://example.com/p/gosuna.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: there is a `<script>` tag inside the .js file?

Comment: Where is your script tag located?

Comment: @Einacio sorry no, bad copy and paste

Comment: @Pekka my script (<script name="gospix" src="http://www.domain.com/p/gospixel.js">) is located in my index.html page of my site

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't use document.write. view this thread: [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Instead, use dynamic object like document.createElement and appendChild.

http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/

This will slove your error.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, the browser is ignoring the autowrite from the import (for security reasons, so an imported script can't modify your page), so you should try making the insert on demand

in gospixel replace the last line with

```
function insertScript(){
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://example.com/p/gosuna.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
```

and then on some other part of the html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    insertScript();
</script>
```

Comment: didn't work, I see the same issue. Is it because of my browser? my hosting? or code?

Comment: is there any `document.write()` inside gosuna.js?

Comment: Yes that file also has some document.write()

Comment: then you are falling on the same hole. the code should only do writes on function call, not by itself

Comment: OK, i'll fix all of them with your solution and I will let you kwow if it's working

Comment: if you're using `document.write()` to create elements, you should also consider using the DOM approach (createElement, appendChild)